# How to store credentials used in an ansible inventory plugin?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I use the Proxmox inventory plugin to get a dynamic inventory. This plugin requires a username and a password in the config yml.

```yaml
# proxmox_inventory.yml
plugin: community.general.proxmox
url: "https://my-proxmox.example.com:8006"
user: "my-user@pam"
validate_certs: no
password: "..."
```

How is it possible to avoid putting a password in clear text in the config ?

Comment: I had a poke around and was unable to find any reasonable docs for how one can supersede that value using env-vars or `ansible.cfg`; as best I can tell, you'll have to "fork" the plugin by copying it into one of `$DEFAULT_INVENTORY_PLUGIN_PATH` and patch `self.get_option('password')` to use `os.getenv` or similar; feel free to [file an issue](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues?q=is%3Aissue+proxmox) cause I agree that's just silly